# I want to get keys as integers using json serialization and deserialization and python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, serialization, deserialization

I have this dict:

```
d={0:[1,2,3,None,1],1:[1,2,4,0,3],2:[4,6,2,3,4],3:[4,2,6,1,2],4:[2,2,6,2,None]}
```

I save it:

```
fo=open("test.json","w")
json.dump(d,fo, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
fo.close()
```

I restore it:

```
fi.open("test.json","r")
g=json.load(fi)
```

And g becomes:

```
{'0': [1, 2, 3, None, 1], '1': [1, 2, 5, 0, 3], '2': [4, 6, 2, 3, 4],...
```

Indexes of the dict have been converted to strings! I need them to be integers. How can I do that easily in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create a new dictionary with integer keys:

```
g = {int(k): v for k, v in g.items()}
```

Comment: Nice one ! It works